# NUnit Selenium Structure

Tags: selenium, nunit

I'm trying to write some Selenium tests with NUnit and doing my best to keep a clean test design (testing one thing for each test). So I got something like this

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeTest
{
   IWebDriver driver;

   [Setup]
   public void Setup()
   {
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test1()
   {
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test2()
   {
   }

   [Teardown]
   public void Teardown()
   {
       driver.Close();
   }
}
```

Now this is fine, but things get insanely slow as the number of tests increase. Starting and stopping the entire browser for each test is a bottleneck.

Any way to keep the browser open until the last test? Or perhaps a better approach/design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to only bring up one browser per fixture you can use [TestFixtureSetUp] [TestFixtureTearDown] instead of [SetUp] and [TearDown]:

```
[TestFixture]
public class SomeTest
{
   IWebDriver driver;

   [TestFixtureSetUp]
   public void Setup()
   {
       driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test1()
   {
   }

   [Test]
   public void Test2()
   {
   }

   [TestFixtureTearDown]
   public void Teardown()
  {
       driver.Close();
   }
}
```

Of course this does not help across fixtures, but could still give some performance gain.

Comment: Perfect! Side note: this doesn't work with Visual NUnit (for Visual Studio), but works as expected with the default NUnit test runner

Comment: It's actually TestFixtureSetUp and not TestFixtureSetup, I edited those to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can make just one method with 'test' in its name. This test method will contain calling other methods (without 'test' in its name). Those other methods will be your tests cases.
Every method with 'test' in its name causes opening and closing browser. By using above solution you will open browser only one time and you will do all your tests cases one by one, at once.